# Laravel eloquent insert data with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, rest, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two models: trainers and trainerClubs. And I have json array. Each json array have a other array.When a json comes to me, I want to add them to the relationship models at the same time. 
for example; Trainer::insert($request->all());

my json example;

```
[
    {
        "identity_no": "111222333",
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "TrainerClubs": [
            {
                "club_id": 1,
                "work_type": 1
            },
            {
                "club_id": 2,
                "work_type": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "identity_no": "444555666",
        "first_name": "jane",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "TrainerClubs": [
            {
                "club_id": 1,
                "work_type": 3
            },
            {
                "club_id": 13,
                "work_type": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and my models;

```
class Trainer extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function TrainerClubs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Modules\Trainer\Models\TrainerClub', 'trainer_id');
    }
}
```

```
class TrainerClub extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id','created_at','updated_at'];

    public function Trainer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Modules\Trainer\Models\Trainer');
    }
}
```

my current working code;

```
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $trainer) {
            $crrTrainer = (array)$trainer;
            $clubs = array_pop($crrTrainer);
            $addedTrainer = Trainer::create($crrTrainer);
            foreach ($clubs as $trainerClub) {
                $addedTrainer->TrainerClubs()->create($trainerClub);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Will these always be new rows?

Comment: Yes, json will be created by excel

Comment: I’d stick to Laravel’s naming conventions. If a trainer can belong to many clubs, then you’d probably just have a `clubs` relation that’s a belongs-to-many `Club`, and `work_type` being a column in the `club_trainer` pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, you can't save both model at the same time. In your case you have to create first the Trainer:

```
 $addedTrainer = Trainer::create($crrTrainer);
```

Later insert the clubs. What you can do different is to create all the clubs at the same time without having to loop through them using `createMany`:

```
$addedTrainer->TrainerClubs()->createMany($clubs);
```